# Sorting Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to add elements to the my linked list order by ascending but my code just hold minimum node of the lists correctly. My function take an argument as data. Anybody have any idea about my fault?

```
while(Node->nextPtr!=NULL && capture!=1) {
    if(Node->nextPtr->data > data){
        capture = 1;
        Node->nextPtr = Temp;
        Temp->nextPtr = nextNode;
    }
    else {
        Node = Node->nextPtr;
        nextNode = Node->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code sample looks incomplete, what is Temp?

Comment: ...and where is your break after condition is met?

Comment: temp is a node and hold data.i mean like temp->data = data;

Comment: i forget break when i write there.my break in if(Node->nextPtr->data > data){... capture = 1..} and while (Node->nextPtr!=NULL && capture !=1)

Comment: @justuser Edit your post instead.

Comment: your while loop seems woring correctly. Jerry Snitselaar & leo code do the same thing but thier code is clearer. what is the problem of your code , what do you want to get you dont obtain it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not something in the lines of:

```
while(Node->data < data && Node->nextPtr!=NULL) Node = node->nextPtr;
Temp->nextPtr = Node->nextPtr;
Node->nextPtr = Temp;
```

Seems clearer, and you don't need to keep track of captured and nextPtr.

(I apologize for any small mistake, it's kinda late here :P)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
//Bubble Sort to sort the elements

 void sort(){

    struct Stack *prev,*curr;

    int temp;

     curr=prev=top;
     curr=curr->next;


    while(curr!=NULL){
        prev=top;
        while(prev!=curr->next){

            if(prev->info<curr->info){

                temp = curr->info;
                curr->info=prev->info;
                prev->info = temp;
            }
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, your sample code is weird and it has been a while since I did a linked list in C but here you go:

```
listNode * insertNode(* listNode newNode){

// throw away variable 32 or 64 bits on the stack, either way no worries since
// it will poof after the call.    
currNode * listNode ;

// assume list head is a global since it normally would be
currNode = ListHead ;


// start from the list head and move through until you hit the end
// if you have not inserted before the end, tack it onto the end

// this will traverse until you hit the tail or data is greater
while(currNode->next and (newNode->data > currNode->data) ) ;

// insert the new node after current node and there is a next node    
if (currNode->next) {
   newNode->next = currNode->next ;
   newNode->*next->prev = newNode ;
   currNode->next = newNode ;
   newNode->prev = currNode ;
}
else
{
   // we hit the end of the list on traversal so just tack it onto the end.
   currNode->next = newNode ;
   newNode->prev = currNode ;
   newNode-> next = null ;
}

// and finally return the node in its proper position.
return newNode ;

}
```

Now this function has no idea what type "data" is and that is fine, but typically it is typed someplace or the data is a pointer type and you can push a pointer size_t bits in to get the actual value. Meh  I think I got it right.